# Cypher Query to CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble writing a Cypher query. I have a `Patient` label that has `Visit` nodes. Each of these `Visits` have data about the visits as relationships. I'm building a export feature where you can export information about each patients visit. Right now my query is `MATCH (p:Patient {patient_id: "some_id"})-[:GOES_TO]-(v:Visit)
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-->(data)
RETURN v, data {.*}`

I want to return a single row with all relationship data for each visit. Right now this query returns a row with a visit and then each relationship properties. So for example a visit on `12/3/2015` will return a row with that date and medication info, but the also return a new row with that date and Vitals information.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a collect() here. Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (p:Patient {patient_id: "some_id"})-[:GOES_TO]-(v:Visit)
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-->(data)
RETURN v, collect(data {.*}) as data
```

Comment: Yep, Just what I was looking for. Thanks!